# String to int parseInt

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a string to an int but i take an error. Here is my code:

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(ABoard[first]);

if (computerBoard[foo] != -1) {
    second = computerBoard[foo];
} else {
    second = board.getRandomPosition();
    while (first==second) {
        second = board.getRandomPosition();
    }
}
```

I want to take a number (int) from a string array and then to take the value of this number from an int array if the value of this number isn't -1.

Comment: An error in any programming language is a meaningful piece of information. So read it, understand it, and at a minimum when asking for help *post the actual error*

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: stacktrace would be helpfull.

Comment: This is the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8 "" @MichałKordas

Comment: What digit did you expect Java to assign to the whitespace in that string? You need to `trim()` your input before you parse it.

Comment: Where's the code for what ABoard is, and what exactly did you input and how did you store it? There's not enough information here to solve your problem, the only thing we can say for sure (if that error message is 100% correct letter for letter) is that you didn't `trim()` your input.

Comment: yes the problem solved with trim! thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim off all of the whitespaces before you parse,

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(ABoard[first].trim());
```

Or replace all non numeric digits

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(ABoard[first].replaceAll("[^0-9\\-]", ""); //including 0-9 and -
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse `String` to `int` you need to remove all non-numeric characters from it (assuming we are not interested in negative integers).

Here is the code to do that:

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt(ABoard[first].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```